# Regex: Remove quotes from within starting and ending quotes - javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to remove the single quote below after 10 and replace with empty string.

So 100,50,"bla 10" bla",20,"another string"

becomes

100,50,"bla 10 bla",20,"another string"

I was so close but the following is selecting 0"

/[^"]"[^$"]/g

Any thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: Use [`s.replace(/([^"])"(?=[^"])/g, "$1")`](https://regex101.com/r/bgtOTv/1) or even [`s.replace(/\b"\b/g, '')`](https://regex101.com/r/bgtOTv/2)

Comment: Is this a literal match of 10"L, or there a pattern to target?

Comment: My bad. As above. But it is a comma seperated string. Let me edit above to show what I mean.

Comment: Essentially I want to remove any quotes that occur between the start and ending quotes in the comma seperated elements above. So I guess it would be remove any " that occurs between ," and ",

Comment: Check my answer and let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: Thanks - but as above I removed the L. (Reason I included L originally was to show there was another character being selected). So string should be 100,50,"bla 10" bla",20,"another string". Want to remove the quote in between "bla 10" bla", leaving other quotes untouched

Comment: You may use `s = '"' + s.replace(/"/g, '') + '"'`

Comment: Dont think that will work for: 100,50,"bla 10" bla",20,"another string". Nice suggestion though! :-)

Comment: @thewildrover Ok, see edit, sir.

Comment: Looks like my answer also solves `100,50,"bla 10" bla",20,"another string"` as well

Comment: Saying syntax error for this line: var res = splits.map(x => x.replace(/(^,?"|"$)|"/g, '$1')).join(',');

Comment: If you are not targeting ES6, use https://jsfiddle.net/bv9hodbm/2/

Comment: cool that returned: 100,50,,"bla 10 bla",20,,"another string" for me. so not doing the job. also as per below this is not generic enough to handle: 100,50,"bla 10" bla",20,"another string","string"

Comment: Ok, looks like that was the post-process issue, see [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bv9hodbm/3/).

Comment: Ok adjusted your code. i think the follwowing works finally: var s = '100,50,"bla 10" bla",20,"another string","string"';
var splits = s.match(/(?:^|)".*?"(?=,|$)|[^",]+/g);
var res = splits.map(function(x) {
   return x.replace(/(^,?"|"$)|"/g, '$1'); 
 }).join(',');
console.log(res);

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```js
var s = '100,,50,"bla 10" bla",20,"another string","string"';
var splits = s.split(/(?:^|,)(".*?")(?:,|$)|,/);
splits = splits.filter(function (x) { return x !== undefined;});
console.log(splits);
var res = splits.map(function(x) {
   return x.replace(/^,*(")|("),*$|"/g, '$1$2'); 
 }).join(',');
console.log(res);
```

**Details**

- `(?:^|,)"` - match `,` or start of string
- `(` - start of the capturing group
- `"` - a `"`
- `.*?`  - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `"` - a `"`
- `)` - end of the capturing group
- `(?:,|$)` - a `,` or end of string
- `|` - or
- `,` - a comma

After we get all the matches, the `.replace(/^,*(")|("),*$|"/g, '$1$2'` removes all `"` but at the start/end of the matches. Its details:

- `^,*(")|` - matches `,` 1 or more times at the start of the string (`^`) and then captures a `"` into Group 1, or
- `("),*$|` -  captures a `"` at the end of the string (`$`) and then 0+ `,`s into Group 2 or
- `"` - matches any other `"`.

The `$1$2` replacement pattern "restores" the `"`s captured into Group 1 and 2 (i.e. keeps the `"`s that are either at the start of the string with an optional `,` in front or end of the string and removes all others).

Comment: Above doesnt work when empty string added between commas eg: '100,,50,"bla 10" bla",20,"another string","string"'

Comment: @thewildrover Check now.

Comment: Ok while the above works fine using the interaction you have created above, but when I copy the code and run the above in google apps scripts I get extra spaces/commas. Heres the result I get: "100,,,,50,"bla 10 bla",20,"another string","string"". Why would the strings returned be different? I dont get it. Different versions of Javascript?